# How to make rectangle background that cut from right side like tilt in jetpack compose android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to make the background in which the right side should be cut like the inside tilt in jetpack compose. Please see the image URL for reference:

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WacjY.png)

I tried box for this but did not achieve cutting from the left side like the image maybe it will be done from canvas but no idea how to achieve it. I'm expected to cut the shape from the end as tilt in jetpack compose in Android.

So far my code:

```
 Box(modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentSize()
                .padding(top = 5.sdp)
                .background(Color.Yellow)
        ){  BoldTextComponent(
                value = workoutViewModel.getFeatureWorkoutResponseData.value.title ?: "",
                textSize = 12.ssp,
                textColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSecondary,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.CenterStart)
                    .padding(start = 4.sdp)
            ) }
```

Comment: Can you add some code what did you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Canvas` for making custom shapes. You can use `Canvas` composable or use `drawBehind` **modifier** of composables to get the desired result.

**Explanation**

First of all we have taken a **path** and then `draw a rectangle` on canvas and `clip the rectangle to path` so it give the desired result.

**Preview**

[image: preview]

**Full Code**

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.drawBehind
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.BlendMode
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Path
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.clipPath
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun Stack09(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {


    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(color = Color.Magenta)
    ) {

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(5.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(50.dp)
                .drawBehind {
                    val trianglePath = Path().apply {
                        moveTo(0f, 0f)
                        lineTo(x = size.width, y = 0f)
                        lineTo(x = size.width - 50f, y = size.height)
                        lineTo(x = 0f, y = size.height)
                    }

                    drawPath(
                        color = Color.Red,
                        path = trianglePath,
                        blendMode = BlendMode.DstOut
                    )

                    clipPath(trianglePath) {
                        drawRect(
                            color = Color.White,
                        )
                    }
                },
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {

            Text(
                text = "4 Core Carvers Routine",
                fontSize = 25.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
            )
        }
    }
}
```